# returning the value of private dynamic int results in seg fault

Tags: c++, class, pointers, segmentation-fault, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm doing a quick test to see how to get the value of a dynamically allocated private data member to another dynamically allocated variable outside of the class, but I'm having trouble returning their value. Whenever I try, I result in a segmentation fault at runtime. I've been slowly simplifying the code and even reduced to an int data type I can't get it to work. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
class testing{
    public:
        testing();
        int getValue();
    private:
        int* asdf;
};
int main(){
    int* test = NULL;
    int test2, test3;
    testing test1;

    test2 = test1.getValue();
    test  = new int(test2);
    test3 = *test;

    std::cout << test3 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
testing::testing(){
    int* asdf = new int(3);
}
int testing::getValue(){
    return *asdf;
}
```

I expect the code to print out just 3, but it doesn't. What am I messing up?

Comment: The [compiler warning](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Psxx9b3v3) gives a good hint.

Comment: `int* asdf = new int(3);` doesn't perform assignment on the data member `asdf`; but initialize a local variable `asdf`.

Comment: @songyuanyao Oh, Other problem was also there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is null pointer referencing problem in here. Allocate some memory and initialize the `test` or make `test` point some other int.

EDIT : As @songyuanyao pointed out, the constructor did not initialized original `testing::asdf`, but new local variable `asdf`. You also should remove `int*` specifier to avoid that problem.

```
int main(){
    int* test = NULL;    //null pointer. You did not give any valid address.
    int test2, test3;
    testing test1;

    test2 = test1.getValue();
    test  = new int(test2);
    test3 = *test;       //ERROR! Trying to dereference the null pointer

    std::cout << test3 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
testing::testing(){
    asdf = new int(3);  // removed int*, as original expression does hide your member variable.
}
```

Additionally, naked `new` expression easily produces memory leak problem. I recommend you to be familiar to the smart pointers in C++.